# I don't make it into the while loop: switch statement

Tags: c#

im just trying to learn about switchstatement.
my porgram is about finding the right case to break the loop, but it doesnt work.

i've type this but when i start the program, it never get into my while loop

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string name;
        int number = 4;
        

        Console.WriteLine("welcome, you need to find yourself.");
        Console.WriteLine("but first tell me your name.");
        name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("what a nice name " + name);
        Console.WriteLine("press a key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey();


        while (number != 4) {

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("pick a number between 1-4.");
            number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (number) {
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("you're not here.");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("you found " + name + " Congratz!");
                    break;
                default: 
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Press a key to try agian :(");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

While loops are never executed if the condition isn't matched (which yours isn't). Maybe try a do-while loop.

```cs
int number = 4;
while(number != 4)
{
  //will never run.
}

do
{
  //will run at least once.
} while(number != 4);
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Of course you could stick with the while loop if you just initialized `number` to anything but 4. If this answered your question, try _accepting_ the answer so SO can shelve this.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution :**

If you carefully notice that you have declared variable `number` to `4`.

[`int number = 4;`]

And never modified it again , outside the loop .

Therefore, the value of `number` remains `4` and never changes !!

---

***Here is my advice to make the code work :***

Looking at the code you want user to enter press any key , then (I don't know which key is set to correct) when user enters right *key* the loop will start (which will never start because your `number` value is always equal to `4` until it gets in the loop). Then simple switch case will be implemented , but what puts me in question is you are taking input every time the loop runs - **right** - until user enters valid input . But you have also provided what to enter in the question inside loop & the `default` is saying `press a key try again` .
I think then output will be in somewhat this manner *(after the loop runs)* :

`Press a key to try agian :(`

> Console clears

`pick a number between 1-4.`

And i think that doesn't make sense.

---

***Final Note :***

1. Redesign the logic of code and try !
2. It's worth noting that you have to update you `number` value **OR** change the *while loop condition* for working of your loop !!!

**And**

The idea of ***@Jack T. Spades*** will also work!